# Bash Execution Error (-1715): Unable to Mount Volume Path

Tags: macos, bash, shell, scripting

I'm looking for some help with a subroutine I'm writing as part of our back up script for our fleet of Macs. This snippet of the script is checking to see if the Network Volume has been mounted and if not it will mount it. I am  running into an issue where I'm not correctly calling on the variable. I'm not sure if I'm quoting the parameters correctly. Error message:

```
0:29: execution error: Some parameter wasn’t understood. (-1715)
```

The command I'm trying to run:

```
osascript -e 'mount volume "afp://some.server.com"'
```

This works. However, when executing the command the following script does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# SCRIPT TESTING SANDBOX

archive_volume="/Volumes/Users"
volume_path="afp://some.server.com"

# Check and see if the Network share is mounted already
if [[ -d "${archive_volume}" ]]; then 
  echo "The Archive Network share is already mounted."
  exit 1
else
  echo  "\nMounting volume...Please enter your OD credentials."
  # Wait for a bit to mount the drive so we catch the message
  sleep 1
  # Mount the share volume
  osascript -e 'mount volume "${volume_path}"'
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Try replacing `osascript` with `echo`.  You should then see what is wrong, e.g. variable replacements inside of '.

Comment: Variable substitution doesn't happen inside single-quoted strings.

Comment: Great debugging tips. Not sure why it did not occur to me to use echo any earlier to troubleshoot. I've done as suggested: `echo "${volume_path}"`. It seems to print back the variable name `some.server.com`. It must be how I'm passing quotation marks on the command... @Ned Deily

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew. Variable substitution is a bit more advance than my current knowledge of bash scripting. How would you suggest we go about referencing the variable with the appropriate quoting?

Comment: Something like `osascript -e "mount volume \"${volume_path}\""` should work.

Comment: @Andrew: You are a Godsend. Thanks so much! My knowledge of variable substitution is limited. Mind if you could explain the meaning behind the use of the "forward slashes" `\"${some_variable}\"`?

Answer (score 0):

> > Something like `osascript -e "mount volume \"${volume_path}\""` should
> >     work. – Andrew Medico
>
> Mind if you could explain the meaning behind the use of the "forward
>   slashes" `\"${some_variable}\"`? – Tan

[Bash Reference Manual, Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting):

> A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with
>   a backslash.

In the command without the **backslashes** (`\`)

```
osascript -e "mount volume "${volume_path}""
```

the `"` before `${volume_path}` would end the first partial string `mount volume` , the `"` after `${volume_path}` would begin the (empty) last partial string; those strings and the expansion of `${volume_path}` would still be concatenated to one argument, e. g.
`mount volume afp://some.server.com`, but the `"` wouldn't be in the resulting argument string, whereas with `\"` those double quotes (backslashes removed) are part of the argument:
`mount volume "afp://some.server.com"`.

If you want the expansion of `${volume_path}` to be explicitly quoted (to allow for spaces and other special characters), you can as well write

```
  osascript -e "mount volume '$volume_path'"
```

(variable expansion takes place, because inside `"` the `'` don't have their inhibiting meaning).